# Updating hash type attribute in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I want to update hash type attribute in Mongoid.

Here is an example

```
class A
 include Mongoid::Document

 field :hash_field, :type => Hash
end
```

Now Let us assume that there is already populate data, like,

```
A.last.hash_field 
=> {:a => [1]}
```

Now I wanted to update the hash and wants final output to be `{:a => [1,2]}`

I tried as

```
a = A.last
a.hash_field[:a] << 2
a.save
=> true

a.hash_field
=> {:a => [1,2]}
```

But when I query as

```
A.last.hash_field
=> {:a => [1]}
```

Thanks means actually it didn't updating anything
Now How could I update as desired?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

This could be related to the way Mongoid shallow copies hashes. If so, then this might help http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/04/13/mongoid-hash-field-types-watch-out/

Note: I haven't tested the solution for your particular situation

Comment: adding the deep_copy and explicitly calling helped me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with how Mongoid optimizes field updates. Specifically, since you're updating an element inside the hash field, the field "watcher" doesn't pick up the update within as the field's own value (pointing to the hash) remains unchanged.

The solution I adopted was to provide a general purpose serializer for any complex object I wanted to store (e.g. Hash). This upside is that it is a general-purpose solution and just works. The downside is that it prevents you from querying on the inner fields of the hash using built-in Mongo operations and also some additional processing time.

Without further adieu, here is the solution.
First, add this definition for a new Mongoid custom type.

```
class CompressedObject
  include Mongoid::Fields::Serializable

  def deserialize(serialized_object)
    return unless serialized_object
    decompressed_string = Zlib::Inflate.inflate(serialized_object.to_s)
    Marshal.load(decompressed_string)
  end

  def serialize(object)
    return unless object
    obj_string = Marshal.dump(object)
    compressed_string = Zlib::Deflate.deflate(obj_string, Zlib::BEST_SPEED)
    BSON::Binary.new(compressed_string)
  end
end
```

Second, in your `Model` (that includes `Mongoid::Document`), use the new type like so:

```
  field :my_hash_field, :type => CompressedObject
```

Now, you can do whatever you want with the field and each time it will be serialized correctly.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a little different, but you might benefit from how I solved it.
I had an Array of hash maps field in my mongo Document, and this is the form that eventually handled it:

```
<% @import_file_import_configuration.fieldz.each do |fld| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="import_file_import_configuration[fieldz][][index]" value='<%=fld["index"]%>'/>
    </td><td>
      <input type="textbox" name="import_file_import_configuration[fieldz][][name]" value='<%=fld["name"]%>'/>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I store maps with 2 keys each ("index" and "name") in my array.
This what my Documents definition looks like:

```
class Import::FileImportConfiguration
  field :file_name, type: String
  field :model, type: String
  field :fieldz, type: Array, default: []
end
```